# Blur the edges of image in Python

Tags: python, numpy, edges

I'm trying to read a binary RGB image and blur just the edges. This is my non-working code upto now. I get this error: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2048,2048,3) (2048,2048)"

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load image
img = cv2.imread('mask.png')


# Get edges
edges = cv2.Canny(image=img.astype(np.uint8), threshold1=100, threshold2=200) # Canny Edge Detection

#Remove edges from image
img = img - edges

# Blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(edges, (0,0), sigmaX=2.5, sigmaY=2.5, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

img = img + blur

# save output
cv2.imwrite('bw_image_antialiased.png', img)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Faster, more efficient?

[image: The images]

Comment: Please share your input image and the expected result - or a mockup of the expected result done with GIMP or Photoshop. Thank you.

Comment: Added the images. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: always google the error. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ValueError%3A+operands+could+not+be+broadcast+together+with+shapes -- subtracting a canny won't "remove edges". this is a numpy error. you should have included the complete traceback in your question because it's not clear which line caused the exception. you can use `img = img - edges[:,:,None]` to add a dimension to make numpy's broadcasting happy.